# Mongoose `$project` how to avoid duplicate document

Tags: mongoose, aggregation-framework

I was facing issue in `$projection`. Actually i am have two separate collection `AddToCart` and `Product` collection. `add_to_cart_products` its an array of object. If the `add_to_cart_products` length is `1` it retrieve correct format. And if it greater than one means it prints twise.

**AddToCart Collection**

```json
[
{
    
      "add_to_cart_user": "5f0076b7bd530928fc0c0285",
      "add_to_cart_products": [
        {
          "product": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70826",
          "product_item": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70877",
          "product_quantity": 5
        },
         {
          "product": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70827",
          "product_item": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70666",
          "product_quantity": 3
        }
      ],
      "add_to_cart_product_total": 5,
      "add_to_cart_discount": 50,
      "add_to_tax": "5eae321d21924800122f978e",
      "add_to_cart_grand_total": 500
    }
]
```

**Product DB:**

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70826",
        "product_name": "2Gingers",
        "product_items": [
            {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70877",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70827",
        "product_name": "Alverty",
        "product_items": [
            {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70666",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Add To LookUps and Projection:**

```
  lookups: [
      {
        from: 'shop_db_products',
        let: {
          productId: '$add_to_cart_products.product',
          purchaseQuantity: '$add_to_cart_products.product_quantity',
          productItemId: '$add_to_cart_products.product_item',
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$productId'] } },
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'shop_db_products',
              localField: 'product_id',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'products',
            },
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: true,
              product: {
                _id: '$_id',
                product_name: '$product_name',
              },
              product_purchase_quantity: '$$purchaseQuantity',
              product_item: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: '$product_items',
                      cond: {
                        $in: ['$$this._id', '$$productItemId'],
                      },
                    },
                  },
                  initialValue: {},
                  in: {
                    _id: '$$this._id',
                    product_size: { $concat: [{ $toString: '$$this.product_size.value' }, '$$this.product_size.unit'] },
                    product_price: '$$this.product_price',
                    product_type: '$$this.product_type'
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $unwind: '$product_purchase_quantity',
          },
        ],
        localField: '',
        as: 'add_to_cart_products',
        model: 'ProductModel',
      },
    ],
```

**Curent Response:**

```json
{
    "_id": "5fa257b3eb6a3f6e3e02ff3f",
    "add_to_cart_status_is_active": true,
    "add_to_cart_discount": 50,
    "add_to_cart_tax": 8,
    "add_to_cart_products": [
        {
            "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54c",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70826",
                "product_name": "2Gingers"
            },
            "product_purchase_quantity": 5,
            "product_item": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70877",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54c",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70826",
                "product_name": "2Gingers"
            },
            "product_purchase_quantity": 5,
            "product_item": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70877",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54c",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70827",
                "product_name": "Alverty"
            },
            "product_purchase_quantity": 3,
            "product_item": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70666",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54c",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70827",
                "product_name": "Alverty"
            },
            "product_purchase_quantity": 3,
            "product_item": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70666",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        }
    ],
    "add_to_cart_created_date": "2020-11-04T07:26:43.885Z",
    "add_to_cart_modified_date": "2020-11-04T07:26:43.885Z",
    "add_to_cart_no": "ATC00003",
    "add_to_cart_user": {
        "user_full_name": "Vendor",
        "user_email": "vendor@techardors.com",
        "user_phone": "0123456785"
    }
}
```

**Expected Response:**

```json
{
    "_id": "5fa257b3eb6a3f6e3e02ff3f",
    "add_to_cart_status_is_active": true,
    "add_to_cart_discount": 50,
    "add_to_cart_tax": 8,
    "add_to_cart_products": [
        {
            "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54c",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70826",
                "product_name": "2Gingers"
            },
            "product_purchase_quantity": 5,
            "product_item": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70877",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54c",
            "product": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70827",
                "product_name": "Alverty"
            },
            "product_purchase_quantity": 3,
            "product_item": {
                "_id": "5f05a0270b4f3a5c41c70666",
                "product_item_number": "857566003019",
                "product_price": 20.99,
                "product_size": "750ml",
                "product_type": "Bottle"
            }
        }
    ],
    "add_to_cart_created_date": "2020-11-04T07:26:43.885Z",
    "add_to_cart_modified_date": "2020-11-04T07:26:43.885Z",
    "add_to_cart_no": "ATC00003",
    "add_to_cart_user": {
        "user_full_name": "Vendor",
        "user_email": "vendor@techardors.com",
        "user_phone": "0123456785"
    }
}
```

It prints twice. Please, tell me what was the mistake in lookup.

If i remove `{ $unwind: '$product_purchase_quantity', }` in response of `product_purchase_quantity` comes as `[]`.

```
 {
            "_id": "5fa2a09b3c6316482098f6ff",
            "add_to_cart_status_is_active": true,
            "add_to_cart_discount": 50,
            "add_to_cart_tax": 8,
            "add_to_cart_products": [
                {
                    "product": {
                        "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54c",
                        "product_name": "Avery Apricot Sour"
                    },
                    "product_purchase_quantity": [
                        5,
                        3
                    ],
                    "product_item": {
                        "_id": "5f4dddaf8596c12de258df1f",
                        "product_size": "22oz",
                        "product_price": 13.99,
                        "product_type": "Bottle",
                        "product_in_stock": 0,
                        "product_images": [
                            "pro00001-796363011028-1.png"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "product": {
                        "_id": "5f059f8e0b4f3a5c41c6f54e",
                        "product_name": "Avery Dugana"
                    },
                    "product_purchase_quantity": [
                        5,
                        3
                    ],
                    "product_item": {
                        "_id": "5f4dddaf8596c12de258df21",
                        "product_size": "22oz",
                        "product_price": 8.99,
                        "product_type": "Bottle",
                        "product_in_stock": 0,
                        "product_images": [
                            "pro00003-796363001340-1.png"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "add_to_cart_created_date": "2020-11-04T12:37:47.936Z",
            "add_to_cart_modified_date": "2020-11-04T12:37:47.936Z",
            "add_to_cart_no": "ATC00004",
            "add_to_cart_user": {
                "user_full_name": "Vendor",
                "user_email": "vendor@techardors.com",
                "user_phone": "0123456785"
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have mentioned my expected result above

Comment: I tried by removing of `{ $unwind: '$product_purchase_quantity', }` it works but `product_purchase_quantity` response was wrong. I have updated current response above